# Rally Time Entry Item query?

Tags: rally

How do I query rally in the built in report developer for all the TimeEntryItems for an iteration.
I tried:

```
var queryConfig = { type : 'timeentry',
                key  : 'TimeEntry',
                fetch: 'Task,User,Values,Owner,TimeEntryValue,Hours',
                query: '(Iteration.Name = ' + '\"' + targetIterationName + '\")'
            };
```

but it just keeps returning empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queryConfig is returning empty because the iteration attribute does not exists on the TimeEntryItem object directly. The iteration is associated to the task that the TimeEntryItem is associated to which is what is causing this query to be invalid.

To get to the iteration you would have to traverse in this fashion:

TimeEntryItem -> Task -> Iteration

To get the iteration you would have to query for the TimeEntryItem by project or task. You would then need to put the results in a loop and filter them down by iteration through the task attribute.

Would it be possible to provide me more detail on what kind of report you are trying to build and what sort of data you need so I can help point you in the right direction?

Comment: I am trying to build a report that contains all the stories and defects of an iteration.  Each story/defect will have the owner, remaining hours, actual time spent, and estimate of hours, and number of tasks.  each task will then have those same values listed in a table below the story/defect table when you click on a link.  I have everything working except for being abel to get the actual time spent on the story/defect or tasks.